# I've been working "in Linux" or "on Linux"?

Tags: expressions, popular-refrains

I have this question, how should I say:

1. I been working in linux.
2. I been working on linux.

I know that "in" implies something is inside another thing, and "on" is like something is over the other thing, but not literally inside.

I've read this but it didn't help me:
[in a system vs. on a system](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/261236/in-a-system-vs-on-a-system)

Comment: Working on/in Linux: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=working+in+Linux%2Cworking+on+Linux&year_start=1960&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cworking%20in%20Linux%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cworking%20on%20Linux%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Wow excellent tool! I always check how many results throws google for the phrases I made, but this is a lot better!

Answer (score 17):

Those mean different things:

- People actually improving Linux itself are working *on* Linux.
- People who just happen to live there to do other work are in contrast simply working *in* (or *with* or *under*) Linux.

So one of those is right for a given situation but wrong for the others — and vice versa.

Comment: Great explanation, but Linux isn't a place, it is an operating system. So I would reword your 2nd explanation as: "People who just happen to 'be using Linux' to do other work are in contrast simply working in (or with or under) Linux."

Comment: @NoName It's programmer jargon. He would never make a mistake like that. **He lives in Java/Spring land most days, spends a decent amount of time playing with the other JVM languages, and still has a soft spot in his heart for Python**. https://www.techlifecolumbus.com/events-posts/scaletech-monthly-meetup-20/

Answer (score 3):

Both are acceptable, depending on the context:
as highlighted in other answers, a Linux developer updating Linux will use "on", while a Linux user will work "in" Linux. For a Linux user, I prefer "*work in a Linux environment*".

Google statitstics give:

- Work **in**    Linux : 334 000
- Work **on**    Linux : 368 000 (surprisingly high because Linux developers are a minority)
- Work **with**  Linux : 338 000
- Work **under** Linux : 102 000

With Ngram viewer (thanks @Josh61 to make me discover that tool), "with" is twice more used than "in" or "on".

Comment: For a complete answer could you actually state the contexts?

Comment: @chaslyfromUK - Sir, yes sir. I edited my answer.

Comment: I'd like to point out that ‘with’ is almost certainly the correct usage here, if you're trying to avoid more verbose constructions like “I've been working in a <product> (environment / system).”

Answer (score 1):

using IN would be like you are working on a project and your system is Linux, but in case of ON it's like the project is Linux itself.

Comment: This has already been addressed in the other answers.